# Inject new simple javascript to magento backend (as a module)

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

I want to add simple char counter functionality on some of the description and meta field on magento product administration backend. Just like on this below screenshot.

[image: You can see that simple char counter on the right side of meta title and meta description text box]

I did that by adding simple prototype script into one of the JS file which get loaded on magento admin HTML. I choose browser.js (`/js/mage/adminhtml/browser.js`) for that because that is the last script which get loaded on the backend area of my magento installation. This is my prototype script chunk of code:

```
/* ADMIN CHAR COUNTER SCRIPT */
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {

    Element.insert( $('meta_title').up().next().down('span'), { 
        'after': "<div id='meta_title_counter'>Char count: <span id='meta_title_counter_num'>"+(69-$('meta_title').getValue().length)+"</span></div>"
    });
    Element.insert( $('meta_description').up().next().down('span'), { 
        'after': "<div id='meta_description_counter'>Char count: <span id='meta_description_counter_num'>"+(156-$('meta_description').getValue().length)+"</span></div>"
    });
    Element.insert( $('short_description').up().next().down('span'), { 
        'after': "<div id='short_description_counter'>Char count: <span id='short_description_counter_num'>"+$('short_description').getValue().length+"</span></div>"
    });
    Element.insert( $('description').up().next().down('span'), { 
        'after': "<div id='description_counter'>Char count: <span id='description_counter_num'>"+$('description').getValue().length+"</span></div>"
    });

    Event.observe('meta_title', 'keyup', function(event) {  
        $counter = 69-$('meta_title').getValue().length;
        $("meta_title_counter_num").update($counter);
        if($counter < 0){ $("meta_title_counter").setStyle({ color: 'red' }); }
        else{ $("meta_title_counter").setStyle({ color: '#6F8992' }); }
    });
    Event.observe('meta_description', 'keyup', function(event) {
        $counter = 156-this.getValue().length;
        $("meta_description_counter_num").update($counter);
        if($counter < 0){ $("meta_description_counter").setStyle({ color: 'red' }); }
        else{ $("meta_description_counter").setStyle({ color: '#6F8992' }); }
    });
    Event.observe('short_description', 'keyup', function(event) {   $("short_description_counter_num").update(this.getValue().length);  });
    Event.observe('description', 'keyup', function(event) { $("description_counter_num").update(this.getValue().length);    });
});
/* END OF CHAR COUNTER MODULE */
```

I do realize that what I've done is such a quick and dirty trick. I practically edit the core file. That means that this script will removed after an upgrade of magento. My boss ask me to put this functionality into a module. But I don't have any experience on creating magento module. I've tried to find some basic tutorial on how to create simple magento module. But none of those tutorial gives me a way to inject new script. This one may be the closest guide:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/how_to_customize_backend_template_f.e._sales_order_information

but I still don't have any idea at all where to start to begin this simple module creation. I'm sorry if this question feels too newbie, but I really need help here and unlike the usual, this time Google can't help me out (or at least I can't find a good keyword to start googling). So here I am hoping that somebody out there would be glad to help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try in your module file with admin layout updates add

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>your_js_file.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

or even

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>your_js_file.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

to add load your js file on all admin pages.