# Magento backend, capture onclick events on different elements

Tags: forms, magento, onclick, backend, magento-1.7

I've a working backend module with various forms to manage several different tables. On one of the forms I have a radio button group (`radios` element on Magento). Here is the code snippet for this radio group:

```
//radio group
$fieldset->addField('radio_group', 'radios', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('banners')->__('Select campaign type'),
        'name'      => 'title',
        'onclick'   => '',
        'onchange'  => '',
        'value'     => '1',
        'values'    => array(
                        array('value'=>'1','label'=>'Imagen'),
                        array('value'=>'2','label'=>'HTML'),
                        array('value'=>'3','label'=>'Producto'),
                        ),
        'disabled'  => false,
        'readonly'  => false,
        'tabindex'  => 3
));
```

There is no way I can find how to manage the `onclik` and the `onchange` events. Where do I need to add the code? The actions to be executed are simple, I'll just enable/disable other controls on the same page according to the selected radio button.

Any suggestion, sample code, tutorial? I've done lot of *googling* with no luck, I've found lot of samples but all refered to how to setup a new admin form, wich I have already done not once but several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could get around this issue is by adding update layout.xml to your module (or a local.xml)

You can include your js in layout.xml using two different method, the only different is where you need to put your js file

Javascript location : /js/your_js_file.js

```
<adminhtml_xxx_yyy>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>your_js_file.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_xxx_yyy>
```

or

Javascript location : /skin/adminhtml/default/default/your_js_file.js

```
<adminhtml_xxx_yyy>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>your_js_file.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_xxx_yyy>
```

Add a css class name to each radio button

```
$fieldset->addField('radio_group', 'radios', array(
   ......
   'class'     => 'campaign_type',
   ....
));
```

In your_js_file.js   ( http://fiddle.jshell.net/hX2u3/ )

```
$$('.campaign_type').each(function(curInput) {
   Event.observe(curInput, 'click', function() {
        alert('some click logic goes here');
    });
   Event.observe(curInput, 'change', function() {
        alert('some change logic goes here');
    });
});​
```

Comment: Upvoted cause it's more MVC (and modern JS) friendly than inline JS

Comment: ok...will check both options at office tomorrow morning, I do not have Magento here at home

Comment: Hmmm...not working... I already had a banners.xml on the `\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\banners` folder. Is this is the layout file you are talking about? Then I added the 1st code snippet but replacing `<adminhtml_xxx_yyy>` by `<adminhtml_banners_edit>`, is this correct? Then the js file I add it to the `magento\js\banner` folder. I have a doubt, the `('someForm')` should be replaced with my form name? `Dts_Banners_Block_Adminhtml_Banners_Edit_Form` for example? Or just `Form` or leave it like this? going mad with this, can't continue working without solving this issue

Comment: View page source... is the js file included? If it is included open it up in a browser does the file content load?

Comment: No, is not included on the page source.

Comment: This seem to be incorrect <adminhtml_xxx_yyy>... what is your url (after .com)

Comment: Following this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7807772/1297603) managed to include the js on the source code of the page. But now is not answering to the onclick.

Comment: Got it working using jQuery thanks to my partner seating next to me. Will not accept as answer but will add +1 as it pointed out to the right direction.

Comment: My concept is correct you just needed to code it the write way using prototype, but I guess will apply the same concept next time and know who's question to skip. Would be nice if you update the post with your answer so the next person who have this issue would have to also spend 2 days trying to figure it out

Comment: Take a look at my updated code above (which explain the difference between the two methods). Should you put a module specific js in the global /js folder which only contain libraries??? So was my code wrong or you just didnt take the time to look where you should put your js?

Answer (score 2):

```
$fieldset->addField('use_color_filter', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('gtfilter')->__('Usar filtro de cores'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'use_color_filter',
            'onclick' => "javascript: alert('a');",
            'onchange' => "",
            'value'  => Mage::registry("use_color_filter"),
            'values' => array("0" => "Não", "1" => "Sim"),
            'after_element_html' => '<small style="color : red; font-weight : bold;" >Requer que o módulo de cores esteja instalado! Lembrando que o atributo de cores deve estar habilitado para buscas avan�adas! </small>',
            'tabindex' => 1
    ));
```

I've tryed it and work well for me.

Comment: This only work for input type "select" and not "radios" as listed above